# NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath: & symbolic links

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, foundation, nsfilemanager

In my ~/Library/Caches/ directory, I have a symbolic link to my app's bundle, and some symbolic links to images (e.g. "big_picture.png" is a symlink to "small_picture.png"). When I try to check if the symlinks exist, using the NSFileManager's `fileExistsAtPath:` method, it returns `NO`, even when the symlink does exist, and it links to a file that exists as well.

As far as I know, Apple's documentation claims that what I'm trying to do should work. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

fileExistsAtPath might follow the symlink. Maybe you can try a different method -- Use [`attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath:error:). A dictionary will be returned if the file exists, and it will give you the ability to check the file type. To do the latter, call `fileType` on the dictionary and check it against `NSFileTypeSymbolicLink`.

Comment: Updated link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410452-attributesofitem